# Can't write pdf file to upload directory using FPDF

Tags: uploads, filesystem

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(http://lendersmatch.ca/wp-content/uploads/deals/deal1.pdf): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/t21jv08zz60b/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mortgage/fpdf181/fpdf.php on line 1023 
[27-Jan-2018 11:24:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unable to create output file: http://lendersmatch.ca/wp-content/uploads/deals/deal1.pdf in
```

My Code:

```
$filename=$upload_path.'deals/deal'.$page->id.'.pdf';
ob_clean();
$pdf->Output('F',$filename);
```

FPDF:

```
if(!file_put_contents($name,$this->buffer))
    $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
    break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$name` apparently contains a URL. That won't work. Set it to a local path, as you did with `$filename`:

```
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filename = $upload_dir["basedir"] . '/deals/deal' . $page->id . '.pdf';
```

Comment: I am passing `$filename` variable to function as `$name`. So what you mean by setting local path as `$upload_path` already url

Comment: Right, if `$upload_path` is the URL, that explains it. Yes, set a local path and it will work.

Comment: Please show me code to set it as local path

Comment: Your suggested edit was pretty much it. Just keep in mind that most paths WP will return do not have a trailing slash.

Answer (score -3):

You should first open public_html folder on 000wenhostapp.com and open .htaccess file add only one line of code :

```
php_flag output_buffering on
```

Comment: Could you explain why do you think this is an answer?